# Is there a cleaner way to check if a deep nested node exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, exists

Using pure javascript -- no third party / lodash etc.

Given a user looking for the existence of a deep nested node, is there a cleaner way to ensure each parent node exists so as to not return undefined?

Keeping it simple, check that a nested prop has length before performing an action.

The problem is, especially when passing props, at any given node, you could end up with `undefined`.

**Is there a way to avoid checking that each node exists like this:**

```
if( !!Grandparent && !!Grandparent.Parent && !!Grandparent.Parent.child && !!Grandparent.Parent.child.prop3.length){
    // do something
}
```

**Something more like this:**
(which I know is not correct as any node being `undefined` hoses the process).

```
if(!!Grandparent.Parent.child.prop3.length) {
    // do something
}

// OR

if(typeof Grandparent.Parent.child.prop3.length !== "undefined"){
    // do something
}
```

EX:

```
   Grandparent: {
        Parent: {
            child: {
                prop1: 'alpha',
                prop2: 'beta',
                prop3: [
                    item: {
                        name: 'first',
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    item: {
                        name: 'second',
                        type: 'number'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [null-safe optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? There are also various implementations of `get`- and `dig`-like methods, but `?.` is cleaner (IMO).

Comment: Use optional chaining operator. `if (foo?.bar?.zoo?.etc) {…}`

Comment: However if `foo` is undefined , you still get undefined.
Here's a codedsandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-hellman-b4z9f?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have indicated, modern JavaScript provides the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which you can use like this (as long as you're not still trying to support IE):

```js
const
  grandparent = getObject(),
  itemsCount = grandparent?.parent?.child?.prop3?.length,
  oops = grandparent?.parent?.child?.length;
console.log(itemsCount ?? "No such property");
console.log(oops ?? "No such property");


function getObject(){
  return {
    parent: {
      child: {
        prop1: 'alpha',
        prop2: 'beta',
        prop3: [
          { item: { name: 'first', type: 'string' }},
          { item: { name: 'second', type: 'number' }}
        ]
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I've encountered an issue in that if any of these are undefined I will get an error. Even if checking the null-safe operator for typeof object !== undefined.
Here's my codesandbox what am I doing wrong?
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-hellman-b4z9f?file=/src/index.js

Comment: The problem was that in your sandbox, the variable `props` was not just undefined but totally **undeclared**. The compiler didn't know what to do about that and threw the problem back to you with an error.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I just came to the same conclusion -- Sometimes its the little things that get me. Appreciate your help.